# How to fix CouchDB segmentation fault

Tags: couchdb

After I installed couchdb on a shared hosting from source, couchdb runs fine (uploads, browsing) until i run map reduce for temporary views. Most of the queries I tried crash the server which quits with:

```
Segmentation fault
```

I tried to turn log_level=debug on but it doesn't produce any messages beyond Segmentation fault? I also tried building new openssl as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Troubleshooting#Segmentation_faults_and_bus_errors)

I suspect it's related to a particular field turning up in the key of the result or how many distinct values this key has in the field.

For example when I run this runs fine:

```
emit(doc.short_value,1)
emit("some long text",1)
```

However this fails (segmentation fault server crash):
    emit(doc.long_value,1)
    emit(doc."some long text"+short_value,1)

Judging from the debug output: for each non-working query the segmentation fault always occurs at the same place/document.

How can I debug this further?

**Update:**

The couchdb version is couchdb [vendor] version="1.4.0".
Spidermonkey is 1.8.5, I have to admit I'm confused by JS 185 vs MozJS 17.0
I used [185](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/js185-1.0.0.tar.gz) because MozJS didn't work and the [docs on my hosting](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/13349/cant-build-couchdb-130)

Comment: How long short_value and long_value in bytes?

Comment: What do you mean? That I should experiment to change the datatype? Right now they are strings.

Comment: I mean how much long string should be to produce segfault.

Comment: I doesn't seem to be related to the length of the string. I updated the question

Comment: are you able to tell if this is occuring in CouchDB itself or in the query server? what exact version of couchdb do you have installed? what version of spidermonkey?

Comment: I updated the question about the version, how can I tell the difference between the DB and the query server? I run couchdb -b from the shell and that process exits